# Maximize function parameter such that constraint is satisfied on entire domain

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I want to find the greatest value for `At` such that the constraint `f[At,x]<=0.5` is satisfied *for every value of x*.

I would try something like

```
NMaximize[{At, (f[At,x]<=0.5) && (100 <= At <= 1000) && 100<=x<= 10000}, {At}]
```

which does not work, presumably, because `x` is an unknown not set as a variable -- but, precisely, I don't want to obtain a value for it.

I want to obtain the `At` such that the constraint is valid for every value of `x`, i.e., such that the graph of the function, parametrized by that value, never crosses the horizontal line at 0.5.

Comment: What is the definition for the function `f`?

Comment: @BobHanlon It is very complicated and refer to external files on my true problem, that's why I didn't produce a MWE. But I thought the general description of the problem would be enough in this case, was I wrong?

Comment: Without executable code we cannot be sure of the problem. If the code is complicated you may only be getting a local maxima (see docs for `NMaximize`). Did you try `Maximize`?

Comment: @BobHanlon but the matter of optimization eficacy aside, your saying that the code above is appropriate to my purpose, in principle?

Comment: I don't know. Without being able to run the code I am just guessing. I would think that you would need `NMaximize[{At, f[At, x]<=1/2, 100 <= At <= 1000, 100<=x<= 10000}, {At, x}]` and depending on the function `f` you might need to specify a `WorkingPrecision` to use arbitrary-precision (i.e., avoid machine precision) calculations.

Comment: @BobHanlon But that would give me the single x-value which allow for At be a maximum while still having f<=1/2. That is not what I want, which is the whole point. I want want it to give me the maximum At which guarantees that the function never crosses the 1/2 line, no matter the x -- which is very different. I believe my code is not running precisely because x is not set as a variable, but I don't want it to do what it would if I set it.

Comment: @BobHanlon You are right about needing to set a numerical precision, thank you!